# How can I use a macro as the (main) argument to \includegraphics

Tags: macros, expansion, includegraphics

Disclaimer: I have tried to find an anser already, but everything I've found refers to the *optional* argument of `\includegraphics` or to other macros with their specific implementations.

I'm working on a (LuaLaTeX) package that includes images generated with an external program.

```
\lily{ c' }
```

will wrap the content `c'` in a proper document, invoke the LilyPond score writer to produce a score and then include the resulting PDF in the `.tex` document (using something like `tex.print('\includegraphics{<resulting-file-hash>}')`

In order to make it possible for secondary packages to *use* the generated results I implemented an option `raw-pdf` that instead of issueing the `\includegraphics` simply prints the generated hash back to the .tex document (`tex.sprint(<generated-filename>)`)

```
\lily[raw-pdf]{ c' }
```

works correctly and will print the generated filename in the compiled .tex document.

But when I try to do

```
\includegraphics{\lily[raw-pdf]{ c' }}
```

I receive an error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<argument> \@protected@testopt \lily 
                      \\lily {}[raw-pdf]{ c' }
l.19 ...dafter\includegraphics{\lily[raw-pdf]{ c' }}
```

I assume this has something to do with expansion, but I'm completely at a loss here as to what is actually happening. I was told to try

```
\expandafter\includegraphics{\lily[raw-pdf]{ c' }}
```

but that doesn't help.

Here's a full minimal example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lyluatex}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{\lily[raw-pdf]{ c' }}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `lyluatex` package must be used from https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex and not the version already in TeXLive!

Comment: As your command seems to have an optional argument it is probably  not expandable.

Comment: Maybe you should create two different macros, one for `raw` and the other which uses `tex.print('\includegraphics{...}')`. This way you might be able to create a fully expandable raw version.

Comment: The problem is that in reality the `\lily` command will have to accept more optional arguments from the document authors

Comment: @uli_1973 Can you please fully specify the syntax for `\lily`?

Comment: This is difficult because the code is distributed over a number of places in the package. But David Carlisle's answer led us on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use macros that expand to a name in the argument but not arbitrary definitions, your example is like

```
 \includegraphics{\def\foo{aaa}\def\zz{bbb}\foo\zz}
```

which does not work.

What does work is

```
  \def\foo{aaa}\def\zz{bbb}\includegraphics{\foo\zz}
```

So you need to arrange that the macros that you use return the name in some macro which can then be used with `\includegraphics`.

That is instead of

> In order to make it possible for secondary packages to use the generated results I implemented an option `raw-pdf` that instead of issueing the `\includegraphics` simply prints the generated hash back to the .tex document `(tex.sprint(<generated-filename>))`

you probably want to make `\lily[raw-pdf]{..}` define a macro say `\lilyrawpdf`  then you can do

```
\lily[raw-pdf]{...}\includegraphics{\lilyrawpdf}
```

Note that this is not specific to `\includegraphics` if you look at your own `\lily` command it is likely that

```
\lily{\def\foo{c}\foo}
```

does not work like

```
\lily{c}
```

or

```
\def\foo{c}\lily{\foo}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what someone did by now (presumably upon your answer): https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex/commit/71651567dd4ed9c4feec8a9ba4201fc53658def9